# Can I use both scanf and getchar together to read a file?

Tags: c, scanf, text-files, stdin, getchar

I am trying to read a text file. There are three sections in the file. The first line always initialises the size of a piece of land, the following lines up to the '&' apply characteristics of the land, then the last few lines describe movement through the land.

Example input:

```
4x4
(0,0)
(3,3)
&
(0,0)>(0,1)>
(0,2)>(0,3)
```

So far, I have got the 4x4 to be stored as needed but, after this, how do I:

1. continue from line 2 processing the lines differently
2. end that process at '&' and continue processing the last lines differently

My code that does not work:

```
/* process first line */
while (c != "\n") {
    scanf("%dx%d%c", &row, &col, &c);
    printf("The land is %d high and %d wide.%c", row, col, c);
}

/* process until '&' is found */
while (c = getchar() != '&') {
    printf("c=%c\n", c);
}

/* process rest of file */
while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
    /* do something else */
}
```

Comment: The only part of your code that is correct (probably) is the `printf` statements. Every other line contains at least one bug.

Comment: A better approach would be to use `fgets` to read each line, and `sscanf` to parse the line. Mixing `scanf` with `getchar` *can* be done, but it's not recommended because of the quirks in whitespace handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues that you have.

First of all, a character constant is denoted by single quotes, like so:

```
while (c != '\n')
```

Second of all, instead of using `x` in the format string, you can use `%*c` to eat all the characters, like this:

```
scanf("%d%*c%d%c", &row, &col, &c);
```

You should also add extra parentheses here to properly check inequality, like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '&')
```

Same here:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```